# "Встретить лицом к лицу образчик развитого стиля"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Монастырь Вознесения труднодоступен, не всякий готов потратить пару
>   дней на дорогу к нему, но важно было встретить лицом к лицу образчик
>   развитого стиля.

[Речь о](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB)

> Белый ангел (серб. Бели анђео) — фреска из церкви Вознесения сербского
>   православного монастыря Милешева, один из шедевров сербского и
>   православного искусства. Датируется XIII веком и относится к периоду
>   Палеологовского возрождения. В XVI веке поверх этого изображения было
>   написано новое, которое было удалено в ходе реставрационных работ в XX
>   веке.
>
> Фреска находится на южной стороне церкви и входит в композицию
>   Жены-мироносицы. Ангел, облачённый в белый хитон, сидит на камне и
>   своей рукой указывает женам-мироносицам на пустую гробницу Христа.

Comment: Может, заменить на "увидеть воочию"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Встретиться лицом к лицу***  – это увидеть воочию, непосредственно, своими  глазами… Штампы? Да,  и довольно потертые от длительного употребления, давно уже не несущие в себе свежего чувства.

***Встретить лицом к лицу*** – это не отворачивая лица, так встречают опасность (и это тоже штамп).

**А как же тогда сказать?** Да и вообще, какой там смысл, ведь его надо правильно выразить. Изображение Белого ангела всем известно, но, может быть,  важно посмотреть  настоящему ангелу  в лицо, поймать его взгляд.  Фразеология здесь уж точно не подойдет.

Только в качестве варианта:

*Монастырь Вознесения труднодоступен, не всякий готов потратить пару дней на дорогу к нему, **но так много значила эта встреча лицом к лицу с …***

**С кем?**  Это еще один вопрос, здесь надо что-то художественное. Но только не образчик, в этом слове может быть негативная коннотация.

**Примечание**

Я вот что вспомнила. Героиня современного романа Анны Матвеевой «Завистливое чувство Веры Стениной» обладала удивительным качеством – **она слышала, как разговаривают персонажи на картинах, чувствовала запахи изображенных там предметов**. Но это были произведения настоящих художников, не ремесленные подделки под искусство.

Фантастика, но как знать?  Может быть,  возможен такой информационный феномен. В любом случае было бы интересно увидеть   Белого ангела и как бы переглянуться с ним. А вдруг…

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Читаю еще раз:

***Монастырь Вознесения труднодоступен, не всякий готов потратить пару дней на дорогу к нему, но важно было встретить лицом к лицу образчик развитого стиля.***

**Можно ли так оставить?** Нет проблем: грамматика правильная, запятые на месте, значение слов соответствует словарю.

**Правда, это не просто текст, а текст художественный.** Как говорят критики, в нем должна быть многомерность и художественное пространство, а оно от правильности грамматики напрямую не зависит. Именно поэтому настоящие книги хочется читать и перечитывать: каждый раз будто входишь в новый мир, видишь его по-другому, испытываешь разные чувства.

**По этому тексту чувства автора мне неясны.** Для чего он едет в монастырь, почему ему это важно? ***Образчик высокого стиля*** хочет увидеть? Эти слова по-разному можно понять.

Что бы ни говорили словари, но у слова ***образчик*** есть явная коннотация. В архитектуре и геологии это термины (люди науки к ним привыкли). Но в литературном стиле у этого слова чувствуется нечто уменьшительно-пренебрежительное, которое по-разному можно истолковать.

**Может быть, автор волнуется перед встречей с ангелом** и использует терминологическое сочетание в ироническом смысле, чтобы скрыть это волнение? Но надо это как-то обозначить, кавычки что ли поставить.

Впрочем, это только мнение одного из читателей.

Answer (score 2):

Я как-то ни об одно слово не споткнулась. Лицом к лицу можно столкнуться с чем угодно.

> Лицом к лицу
>   1. Совершенно рядом, в непосредственной близости, очень близко (видеть кого- или что-л.). 2.Непосредственно, вплотную (встречаться,
>   сталкиваться и т.п. с кем-л.). Ср. носом к носу. 3.Непосредственно,
>   по-настоящему серьёзно (соприкасаться, сталкиваться и т.п. с чем-л.).
>   ФСРЯ, 228-229
>   https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/29320/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83

У нас первое значение.

Образчик -  то же самое, что и образец, только разговорное. Иногда используется в стилистике с презрительной интонацией, но далеко не всегда. В архитектуре вообще сплошь и рядом "образчик развитого стиля". Мне кажется, всё нормально.

Answer (score 0):

**Встретиться лицом к лицу с высоким образцом совершенного стиля.**

И ещё. Представление о Вознесении (как и Воскресении) не абстрактно.

**Монастырь Вознесения Господня труднодоступен.**

Comment: Так это же фрагмент текста о: там всё кишит полными и торжественными именованиями. Но вопрос о встрече *лицом к лицу*. С образцом.

Comment: У произведения, тем более истинного, есть лицо. И слово ЛИЦО в фразеологизме не имеет физиологического значения.